# What is the term for single source authentication that is not Single Sign-On?

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on

I've been using the term "Single Source" for authentication schemes that use a single authentication source (e.g. a single LDAP service) but are not Single Sign-on. i.e. You have to log on more than once, but you are using the same credentials.

Is there a commonly used technical term or acronym for "Single Source" authentication? I couldn't find one.

Comment: Perhaps try also try http://english.stackexchange.com/ :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps "Centralized Authentication".

Comment: It's only a preference, but this rings best to me.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard it referred to as "Unified credentials" or "Unified Login".